# Discrepancy Between Camera View and Rendering

Tags: rendering, materials, shadows

Trying to render an image of a protein in blender, and finding that the rendered image has weird shadows on it, when these are not visible in camera view, as per the image below.

Any idea why this may be happening?

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did You check for overlapping faces? If You mean that dark "shadows" strikes thru your "blueish" stripes... Any chance of a .blend so we could look?

Comment: Hi, the .blend would likely be ~200mb... the models are exported from other software and are quite large. Is this normal? Where do people typically upload these things?

Comment: But yes... the dark shadows are appearing on my blue arrows/strands. I think they're coming from the translucent surface mesh which is overlaid, so I've been trying to get rid of that object's shadows but to no avail.

Comment: I think you're right though.. due to faces overlapping between the surface mesh and cartoon representation. Any idea on how to disconnect these two during rendering? I turned off shadows on the stranded (cartoon) object in the cycles settings which helps a but but it looks a bit weird now

Comment: Without the file (at least part of it) its complicated when I could not see anything. Ok, so upload it here: http://myairbridge.com/ ...and paste the link then. **(up to 20GB for upload!)**

Comment: https://mab.to/dzAZ5PlRj There you go!

Comment: Ok so this is the render - DL it and paint the "unwanted" parts (error) for me so I will know what to "tweak" ;) ... http://pasteall.org/pic/360fe7f10f7063424cda94e1c8604390

Comment: What do you mean? I am trying to make it look like the bottom right panel in my original image.

Comment: ...so U sent me the link on file WITHOUT that "blueish" stripes.